# Positioning of a printed datagridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I've been looking for code that import and print DataGridView and I found it.
My purpose is to make a billing system for law firm.
I've printed the name of the lawyer and the adresse and  etc and after that, I want to print the datagridview of the bill but the problem is that,  vb print it over the info of lawyer.
my purpose is to print the gatagridview under the lawyer info .
there was a solution on the internet like:
`e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(blackPen, New Rectangle(position, yPosition, totalWidth,                    height))`
I have tried hard the implement it in the code but it didn't work
Please help

```
        Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As System.Object, e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    'lawyer info
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Facture", New Font("Arial", 24, FontStyle.Italic), Brushes.Blue, New Point(200, 20))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Nom Avocat : " + TextBox17.Text, New Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Italic), Brushes.Black, New Point(20, 60))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Adresse : " + TextBox18.Text, New Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Italic), Brushes.Black, New Point(20, 80))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Ville : " + TextBox19.Text, New Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Italic), Brushes.Black, New Point(20, 100))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Telephone : " + TextBox20.Text, New Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Italic), Brushes.Black, New Point(20, 120))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Email : " + TextBox21.Text, New Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Italic), Brushes.Black, New Point(20, 140))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Site web : " + TextBox22.Text, New Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Italic), Brushes.Black, New Point(20, 160))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Site web : " + TextBox22.Text, New Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Italic), Brushes.Black, New Point(20, 180))

    'positioning of datagriview2




    'insert datagridview
    ' sets it to show '...' for long text
    Dim fmt As StringFormat = New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.LineLimit)
    fmt.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
    fmt.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter
    Dim y As Int32 = e.MarginBounds.Top
    Dim rc As Rectangle
    Dim x As Int32
    Dim h As Int32 = 0
    Dim row As DataGridViewRow

    ' print the header text for a new page
    '   use a grey bg just like the control
    If newpage Then
        row = DataGridView2.Rows(mRow)
        x = e.MarginBounds.Left
        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
            ' since we are printing the control's view,
            ' skip invidible columns
            If cell.Visible Then
                rc = New Rectangle(x, y, cell.Size.Width, cell.Size.Height)

                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightGray, rc)
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rc)

                ' reused in the data pront - should be a function
                Select Case DataGridView2.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment
                    Case DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomRight,
                         DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
                        fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far
                        rc.Offset(-1, 0)
                    Case DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter,
                        DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
                        fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
                    Case Else
                        fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near
                        rc.Offset(2, 0)
                End Select

                e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView2.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).HeaderText,
                                           DataGridView2.Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
                x += rc.Width
                h = Math.Max(h, rc.Height)
            End If
        Next
        y += h

    End If
    newpage = False

    ' now print the data for each row
    Dim thisNDX As Int32
    For thisNDX = mRow To DataGridView2.RowCount - 1
        ' no need to try to print the new row
        If DataGridView2.Rows(thisNDX).IsNewRow Then Exit For

        row = DataGridView2.Rows(thisNDX)
        x = e.MarginBounds.Left
        h = 0

        ' reset X for data
        x = e.MarginBounds.Left

        ' print the data
        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
            If cell.Visible Then
                rc = New Rectangle(x, y, cell.Size.Width, cell.Size.Height)

                ' SAMPLE CODE: How To 
                ' up a RowPrePaint rule
                'If Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells(5).Value) < 9.99 Then
                '    Using br As New SolidBrush(Color.MistyRose)
                '        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, rc)
                '    End Using
                'End If

                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rc)

                Select Case DataGridView2.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment
                    Case DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomRight,
                         DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
                        fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far
                        rc.Offset(-1, 0)
                    Case DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter,
                        DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
                        fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
                    Case Else
                        fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near
                        rc.Offset(2, 0)
                End Select

                e.Graphics.DrawString(cell.FormattedValue.ToString(),
                                     DataGridView2.Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)

                x += rc.Width
                h = Math.Max(h, rc.Height)
            End If

        Next
        y += h
        ' next row to print
        mRow = thisNDX + 1

        If y + h > e.MarginBounds.Bottom Then
            e.HasMorePages = True
            ' mRow -= 1   causes last row to rePrint on next page
            newpage = True
            Return
        End If
    Next
    ' end instert



End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: You should perhaps forget this approach and look at something dedicated to reporting. iText library for creating PDFs is quite common, and even making an HTML page would be easier and offer you more flexibility than this

Answer (score 0):

You start printing `lawyer info` at the absolute coordinates of the paper , then you decide to use ***Margins !!!*** 
try

```
Dim y As Int32 = e.MarginBounds.Top
'lawyer info
e.Graphics.DrawString("Facture", New Font("Arial", 24, FontStyle.Italic), Brushes.Blue, New Point(200, 20 + y))
e.Graphics.DrawString("Nom Avocat : " + TextBox17.Text, New Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Italic), Brushes.Black, New Point(20, 60 + y))
'....

'your code
```

Comment: it dosen't work, I've already tried it .it prints the datagridview over lawyer info

Answer (score 0):

I found a code that I edited and now it works fine
there it is:

```
 'second solution
        Dim leftMargin As Integer = 100 ' Change value to change the x-position of the DataGridView
        Dim position As Integer = leftMargin
        Dim yPosition As Integer = 200  ' Change value to change the y-position of the DataGridView
        Dim height As Integer = DataGridView2.ColumnHeadersHeight
        Dim fmt As StringFormat = New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.LineLimit)
        Dim blackPen As New Pen(Color.Black, 3)

        position = leftMargin
        yPosition = yPosition + DataGridView2.ColumnHeadersHeight
        For Each dr As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView2.Columns
            Dim totalWidth As Double = dr.Width
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.White), New Rectangle(position, yPosition, totalWidth, height))
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(blackPen, New Rectangle(position, yPosition, totalWidth, height))
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dr.HeaderText, New Font("Times New Roman", 10, FontStyle.Bold Or FontStyle.Italic), Brushes.Black, position, yPosition, fmt)
            position = position + totalWidth
        Next

        For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView2.Rows
            position = leftMargin
            yPosition = yPosition + DataGridView2.ColumnHeadersHeight
            For Each dc As DataGridViewCell In dr.Cells
                Dim totalWidth As Double = dc.OwningColumn.Width
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.White), New Rectangle(position, yPosition, totalWidth, height))
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, New Rectangle(position, yPosition, dc.OwningColumn.Width, height))
                e.Graphics.DrawString(dc.Value, New Font("Verdana", 8, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, position, yPosition)
                position = position + totalWidth
            Next
        Next




        
    End Sub
```

`